# When $R$-Module of Rank $r$ has a submodule isomorphic to $R^r$?

Tags: free-modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain,$M$ is a finitely generated  $R$ module. Prove that rank$(M)=r$ iff $M$ has a free submodule $N \equiv R^r$ , such that $M/N$ torsion . If $R$ is a PID then $N$ may be chosen so that $0\to N\to M\to M/N\to 0$ splits.

If rank$(M)=r $ then there exists a maximal independent set of elements of $M$ say $S=\{m_1,m_2,...,m_r\}$ take the free module $R^r$ and an isomorphism $\phi: R^r \to \tilde S$ defined by $$\phi(e_i)=m_i,$$  where $\tilde S$ denote the submodule generated by $S$. Take $N=\tilde S$ if $M/N$ is not torsion there will be contradiction in maximality of $S$. So , one side is done .

How to show the converse part and the case where $R$ is a PID?

Comment: I guess this depends on what you know about rank. The definition of rank I am familiar with (which I believe is equivalent to yours) is $rank(M) = dim_{Frac(R)}(M \otimes_{R} Frac(R))$. In this case, I would tensor the exact sequence $0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$ with $Frac(R)$ and see what gives.